# Following ajax callback function doesn't show/hide the result?

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this work, the #widget-fin div and #wrap div both don't react?

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo dirname(WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.plugin_basename(__FILE__)); ?>/save-route.php",
            data: str,
            success: cb_success
        });


var cb_success = function(msg){

        if(msg.toString() == "OK") 
        {
            result = '<div class="notification_ok">Save!</div>';                
            jQuery('div#widget-fine').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            result = '<div class="notification_ok">Nothing saved</div>';
        }

        jQuery('div#wrap').html(result);
        //alert('test '+ result);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an `alert` at the top of the callback function? Does it appear? If not, then the problem is likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the definition of cb_success in front of the ajax call. cb_success might otherwise be undefined.